# Connecting to vpn in Node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to connect cisco vpn in Node js using cisco-vpn npm package.When i run the code it is getting failed.

```js
const vpn = require('cisco-vpn')({
    server: 'ipaddress',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
    
})
 
vpn.connect()
    .then(() => console.log('connected!')).catch(e => {
        console.log("11",e)
    })
 
// some time later
vpn.disconnect()
    .then(() => console.log('disconnected!')).catch(e => {
        console.log("17 is",e)
    })
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: "17 is Error: Command failed: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Cisco/Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client/vpncli.exe" disconnect"